# MDX calculating a fiscal period average over current YTD and also two previous years

Tags: visual-studio, mdx

I was asked to provide our cube with calculated field with an average (weighed would have been good, but non-weighed is acceptable) of the number of admissions over each fiscal period to date of this year (say period 7) plus the last two full fiscal years - so the other 26 periods from that range).

I've been working on it for a while but the numbers are a bit off and I'm not sure I'm using the correct method:

```
Avg(
{
periodstodate(
[1_Time].[Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year],
[1_Time].[Hierarchy].currentmember)
,
Descendants(
[1_Time].[Hierarchy].prevmember.parent,
[1_Time].[Hierarchy].[Period]
)
,
Descendants(
[1_Time].[Hierarchy].prevmember.prevmember.parent,
[1_Time].[Hierarchy].[Period]
)
}

, [Measures].[admissions]
)
```

The 1_Time hierarchy is pretty simple:  Fiscal year, period (1 to 13) and dates.

I've been testing it using 2016 and I'm getting values that are close, but not correct.

Is there another way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be more laconic here:

```
AVG(
    {[1_Time].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Parent.Lag(2).Children.Item(0):
    [1_Time].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember},
    [Measures].[admissions]
)
```

Explanation + examples:

```
[1_Time].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember -> 3 period 2017
.Parent -> 2017 year
.Lag(2) -> 2015 year
.Children -> set {1 period 2015 year : 13 period 2015 year)
.Item(0) -> 1 period 2015 year

{[1_Time].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Parent.Lag(2).Children.Item(0):
[1_Time].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember}
-> set {1 period 2015 year : 3 period 2017}
```

What do you mean by saying weighed average? Per day level?

Comment: It's a weighed mean or scaled...basically anomalous points of data don't contribute as much (either too high or too low) but the powers that be decided against that this morning...which is fine by me.      I'm just looking to calculate a period average for the periods in the current fiscal year (let's say 3 in 2017) and the two previous fiscal years (26 periods plus the 3 in the current year).

Comment: Just tried your way and the numbers match!  Thank you so much for the great explanation.

Comment: Great to hear! Please check it as answered to make other people sure your problem is solved.

Comment: No problem...I thought I had!   Thanks again!